# Apache SetEnvIf Request_URI does not match URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set HTTP header X-Robots-Tag to "noindex" on any URL starting with /exit/, but i can't figure out why SetEnvIf Request_URI simply does not match my URLs.

Part of my .htaccess file where i'm trying to solve the issue:

```
# For info
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)$ REQUEST_URI=$1
Header set X-Request-Uri "%{REQUEST_URI}e"

# Works
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/.* WHY1
Header set X-Test1 "test1" env=WHY1

# Does not work any more
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/e.* WHY2
Header set X-Test2 "test2" env=WHY2
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/e.* WHY3
Header set X-Test3 "test3" env=WHY3
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/\e.* WHY4
Header set X-Test4 "test4" env=WHY4
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/\e.* WHY5
Header set X-Test5 "test5" env=WHY5

# What i'd like it worked
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/exit/.* NOINDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=NOINDEX
```

This is what i get in network tab in Chrome browser:

```
x-request-uri: /exit/22216832/
x-test1: test1
```

This is what i actually expected:

```
x-request-uri: /exit/22216832/
x-test1: test1
x-test2: test2
x-test3: test3
x-test4: test4
x-test5: test5
x-robots-tag: noindex
```

---

**EDIT**

I sacrificed a little more of my hair and found out that i was actually overwriting Request_URI which seems to be some kind of global variable. After more testing i also figured out that this variable is a little liar:

.htaccess file:

```
# Getting value from a global variable
Header set X-Request-Uri "%{Request_URI}e"

# Expecting that Request_URI1 will have the same value as Request_URI
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)$ Request_URI1=$1
Header set X-Request-Uri1 "%{Request_URI1}e"
```

Network tab in Chrome browser:

```
x-request-uri: /exit/12313/
x-request-uri1: /index.php
```

So Request_URI in the global space is */exit/12313/*, but in case of SetEnvIf it is */index.php* and they say magic does not exist ☺.

Comment: This is a slightly different situation, but the underlying problem is the same: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/httpd-subrequest-variable-inconsistencies.html You can use `<LocationMatch>SetEnv</LocationMatch>` instead. mod_setenvif is a bit difficult to use properly.